# How to use many buttons inside the form of asp.net c# having different functionality

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

This is my first ASP.NET web app and every form without `<form runat="server"></form>` tag is not running plus all element should be inside form tag. Now I have some buttons links for some other pages of my project.

If I use following code it opens new link on another page instead of same page:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonAttendance" OnClientClick="window.open('AttendanceForm.aspx','AttendanceForm')" runat="server" Text="Attendance"
                    CssClass="btn" /><br />
```

And if I use following code then every buttons acts after filling the form elements only:

```
 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAttendance" OnClick=ButtonAttendance_Click() runat="server" Text="Attendance"
                        CssClass="btn" /><br />
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void ButtonAttendance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("AttendanceForm.aspx");    
}
```

My requirement is when click on any button we should redirect to related page directly on the same page without filling any form elements. How it is possible?

Comment: OnClick="ButtonAttendance_Click()"

Comment: Please elaborate on this ' redirect to related page directly on the same page without filling any form elements.' You want to redirect on the same page but a different section?

Comment: Exactly like common behave.... for example W3school.com, As we click on HTML button we will have html tutorial on same page and so on...

Comment: @DipakAkhade w3schools use a masterpage. If I didn't misunderstand you, you want something like some elements will not be change, and other page will be loaded in some section, right? If no, take screenshots of what you need please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code behind looks fine.

If you are using a webform you have to put your controls within the form tags for the postback to work correctly and raise the `OnClick` event on the sever side.

```
<form runat ="server">
 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAttendance" OnClick=ButtonAttendance_Click() runat="server" Text="Attendance"
                        CssClass="btn" /><br />
</form>
```

If you don't need to have the server set values or interact with the buttons on the page just make them regular HTML buttons and use the onclick event for JavaScript to do the redirection.

```
<button id="btnAttendance" onclick="window.location.href='AttendanceForm.aspx';return false;" class="btn">Attendance</button>
```

Comment: Good...!!! I need Second Solution and Worked too but new problem arises that Text of button got invisible. value="Attendance" not working.

Comment: @DipakAkhade just updated my answer. Remove the value attribute and put the text you want the button to say between the opening and closing tags for the button.

Answer (score 0):

instead of window.open use window.location it will open in the same age
           window.location='AttendanceForm.aspx'

Comment: Not Working and Same Problem